# Is it possible to change view while using circle selection?

Tags: modeling

When using selection modes like circle selection (C) or box selection (B) I often would like to change the view to select more faces, vertices or edges that are hidden because of the angle view. Apart from hitting ESC then change angle of the view then press C again is there a hot key to be able to change the view by pressing it and using the mouse buttons/wheel without having to press C or B again afterward?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not, unfortunately.

It is a known limitation of the current modal operator's design. While a modal operator is running, like *Circle Select*, *Border Select*, *Knife Tool*, *Move*, *Rotate*, *Scale*, or any other, Blender can't modify the view.

The opposite is also true: while doing view transforms like Rotating the view or panning, no other tools can operate.

There were some rumors about overcoming this for future 2.8 versions but no definite decisions.